# React Bootstrap ToggleButton triggering function twice

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am having an issue when clicking on my react-bootstrap ToggleButtons. They seem to fire the handlePlatformChange() function twice - it first passes the correct id but then instantly after passes null. One option I came across was to include e.preventDefault() in the function however this prevented the buttons from toggling properly. I have exhausted every option I can think of - any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ToggleButton from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup';

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
        User : "",
        Platform: "battle",
        Player: "",
        Level: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handlePlatformChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({Platform: e.target.id}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.Platform);
    });
  }
    
    
  handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "usernameinput") {
      this.setState({User: e.target.value});
    }
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="infoSection">
          <div className="center">
            <input type="text" id="usernameinput" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Username" /><br/>
            <ToggleButtonGroup id="buttongroup" name="buttongroup" defaultValue={[1]}>
              <ToggleButton id="battle" value={1} variant="secondary" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}></ToggleButton>
              <ToggleButton id="acti" value={2} variant="secondary" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}></ToggleButton>
              <ToggleButton id="psn" value={3} variant="secondary" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}></ToggleButton>
              <ToggleButton id="xbl" value={4} variant="secondary" onClick={this.handlePlatformChange}></ToggleButton>
            </ToggleButtonGroup>
            <br/>
              <Button id="searchButton" variant="primary">Search</Button>
              <div className="displaySection">

                <p id="displayHeader">Username: {this.state.Player}<br/>
                Level: {this.state.Level}</p>
                <p id="displayInfo1">some info here</p>
                <p id="displayInfo1">some info here</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can add condition in `handlePlatformChange` for null.

Comment: You need to do some debug here... on your handlePlatformChange method just console.log(e.target) to check what you get. Looking for your code im guessing that you are not reaching the desirable target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **ToggleButton** element is in fact an input inside a label. Transforming this element into plain html you have (the example for the first button):

```
<label id="battle" variant="secondary" type="button" class="btn btn-default active"
  <input type="radio" name="buttongroup" autocomplete="off" value="1"></input>
</label>
```

The id you want is on label tag but when you click the input you only reach the input tag.

So, to solve your problem you need to change your handlePlatformChange method to:

```
handlePlatformChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({Platform: e.target.parentNode.id}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.Platform);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I did however have to add e.preventDefault() back into my function for it to work properly. I am still receiving two console.log outputs... but I assume this is because the onClick event applies to both the label and the input fields so it's essentially calling the function twice?

Comment: That's right.. you are triggering the click on label and the input. But, you can set the css property "pointer-events: none" to that form labels to avoid click events on those.

Comment: I guess something like that: #buttongroup label { pointer-events: none } would fix your problem.

Comment: Note for future visitors: changing onClick => onChange will also fix this issue.

Comment: @KreepN is correct - the double trigger is there because when the value changes, the onChange handler is called again - check the documentation for this